# Synonyms for "anal retentive"

Tags: adjectives, synonyms

I would like one or more synonyms for *anal retentive*.

I was chatting last night in an [mmorpg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massively_multiplayer_online_role-playing_game), and any message with the word *anal* was banned. I ended up talking about my *canal retentive minus c* guild-mate instead.

Comment: Also, I forgot in my answer (and it's more of a comment): *anal-retentive* takes a hyphen!

Comment: Hah! Trolling in trade chat, I see. I can take a wild guess as to which mmorpg it was. :)

Comment: @fx: it only requires a hyphen if used as an adjective: "He is anal retentive" & "What an anal-retentive way of doing things"

Comment: I saw a sig quote once asking "does 'anal retentive' have a hyphen?".  Of course an anal-retentive person would know, which has led to the shorthand in my social circle of "hyphenated".  E.g. "he's being very hyphenated today". :-)  (And @horatio, it's still an adjective in your first sentence, same as "blue" is in "he is blue".)

Comment: Actually, I should have said "phrasal adjective." But you knew that already.

Comment: Would attempting to say 'anal retentive' cause you to get *expelled* from your mmorpg?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would probably go with ***fussy***. Other possibilities include *finicky*, *persnickety*, *hair-splitting*, or simply the broader *difficult*.

Comment: You forgot 'nit-picking'?

Comment: @Jez: It could go, but without the hyphen: **nitpicking**

Answer (score 6):

"Uptight" or "Type A" (as in 'personality'.)

Answer (score 5):

Less of a synonym than an allusion via an incorrect and overly literal interpretation of what *anal-retentive* means, but for a situation like the one you describe, you may get good mileage out of *constipated*.

Answer (score 4):

I would go with one of the following phrases/words:

- Excessively fussy
- Excessively orderly
- Punctilious
- Finicky
- Persnickety
- Demanding
- Hard to please
- Picky

Answer (score 2):

A few more options:

- **Obsessive**
- [**OCD**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obsessive%E2%80%93compulsive_disorder)
- **Diligent** for a more positive spin. Something tells me this doesn't fit your context though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *perfectionism*.

All the above have negative connotations and being anal-retentive can be very positive — especially in journalism, fact-checking, and mathematics.

Answer (score 0):

- fastidious
- persnickity
- choosy
- finicky
- difficult
- particular

and I really liked

- constipated (;

Answer (score 0):

I would say that 'control freak' is a pretty good synonym for anally-retentive.

Comment: They can be related but I'm not sure that control-freakery equates to obsession over detail.  Control-freaks often don't mind a mess as long as it's *their* mess.